# How to use usehook in a function using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to use useHook in a function and it says useHook is used within a function which is neither a react function component or custom react hook.

i want to use useOpen hook within a function and i get error.

below is my code,

```
import useOpen from './Open';

function hide = () => {
    const open = useOpen(); 
    open.setOpen(true);
}

function useAnother = () => {
    load().then(()=>{
        hide();
    }
}
```

what i have tried?

```
const useHide = () => {

    const open = useOpen(); 

    open.setOpen(true);

}

function useAnother = () => {

    load().then(()=>{

        useHide(); //error here

    }

}
```

Now it throws error react hook cannot be called inside a callback. React hooks must be called within a react function component or custom react hooks.

i am not sure how to fix this. could someone help me fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **Rules of Hooks**, you can only call Hooks at the top level: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

You can solve your problem by calling `useHide` at the top level and returning a function from `useHide` that you can call from anywhere. For example:

```
const useHide = () => {
  const hide = () => {
    console.log("hiding!!!");
  };

  return {
    hide
  };
};

const useAnother = () => {
  const { hide } = useHide();

  load().then(() => {
    hide();
  }
};
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-62317282-kielz

Comment: thanks and useOpen should be used within useHide as const open = useOpen; and pass open to hide within useHide?

Comment: @saritha Yes, you can do that. Or, if you don't want to expose `open` outside of `useHide`, then `useHide` can use `open` inside its `hide` method that it returns to `useAnother`.